# How do i edit raw data from a file in bytes?

Tags: c#, hex, byte, raw-data

I want to edit raw data from files (Hex) but i don't know how can i do it

Is there any package that can help me?

Also how do i convert strings in raw bytes?

I've tried some solutions out of google but none of these worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that:

1. Reads all the bytes from a file
2. Changes the second byte to the decimal value 8
3. Writes the bytes back to the file

Note, this is not the most efficient way to do this, but it's an example.

```
public async Task ChangeSomeBytesInFileAsync(string path)
{
    var bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

    bytes[2] = 0b0000_01000;
    
    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path, bytes);
 }
```

To get the bytes of a string use the **[Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-7.0)** class and the appropriate encoding In this example, I'm using UTF-8.

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"some value");
```